# Sending file via HTTP

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, http

I've seen multiple solved questions regarding this topic in C#, but I can't get it working. Here's what I've done so far

```
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
using (imageStream)
{        
    bp.Save(@"C:\Users\denskie\Desktop\Capture.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    imageStream.Position = 0;

    byte[] imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
    var wc = new WebClient();
    //wc.UploadData("http://localhost:3000/file", "PUT", imageBytes);
    wc.UploadFile("http://localhost:3000/file", "PUT", @"D:\Capture.jpg");
}
```

But it's throwing an error saying:

[image]

On the other side, I have a javascript code that sends a file(image) to my server:

```
var el = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

el.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let files = e.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i];

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('PUT', 'http://localhost:3000/file', true);
    xhr.onload = (event) => {
      console.log('done uploading!');
    };
    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
      let percent = 100 * (event.loaded / event.total);
      console.log(percent+'% uploaded');
    };

    xhr.send(file);
  }
});
```

It's working perfectly fine. I wanna do something like this in c#

Comment: What does the JavaScript request look like in your browser's Developer Tools? Look at the raw request body to see how it's encoded or wrapped (is it meant to be a MIME multipart request or raw file bytes? Can you debug your server-side code to see how it's handling the file?

Comment: Why are you getting the image bytes if you're not doing anything with them? Why are you using two different paths for your file in different locations in your code?

Comment: oh sorry @mason. The image bytes is a screenshot my application produces. That's the thing that I really want to push to a server. I'm just testing out a static file for the meantime

Comment: @Dai If i log the actual file that I send to the server in my js code, the browser console shows this. 

https://ibb.co/kLyqMH

Comment: Can you capture and compare the headers from the js call versus the c# call using fiddler or something else?

Comment: @dens14345 You only posted a small part of the window of a JavaScript object, and not any of the HTTP headers or raw request body. Use a tool like Fiddler or WireShark.

Comment: I solved my issue. 
I added a header "Content-Type" - "image/jpeg" And its all working now.